# CMake dependencies and Dll copies

Tags: c++, cmake

I did wrote some CMake code to transitively get all library dependencies of a given executable target and copy dlls next to it (yes Windows World)

Then I got an external library that does not support CMake. That have a single implib lets call it a.lib with an a.dll, this library also depends on another dll without any available implib (b.dll)

So I wrote a aConfig.cmake like this:

```
set(a_FOUND TRUE)

add_library(a SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(a PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LANGUAGES "CXX"
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${a_DIR}/bin/a.dll"
    IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${a_DIR}/lib/a.lib"
)

add_library(b SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(b PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${a_DIR}/bin/b.dll"
)

# to express a dependency without requiring implib at link time
target_link_library(a PRIVATE b)
```

I end up with this (expected) error

```
IMPORTED library can only be used with the INTERFACE keyword of
  target_link_libraries
```

Then I modified `b` to become an INTERFACE (It feels strange here):

```
add_library(b INTERFACE IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(b PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${a_DIR}/bin/b.dll"
)
target_link_library(a INTERFACE b)
```

with CMake 3.18 my transitive loop does not want to ask for an IMPORTED_LOCATION on an INTERFACE

```
  INTERFACE_LIBRARY targets may only have whitelisted properties.  The
  property "IMPORTED_LOCATION" is not allowed.
```

but with CMake 3.19 it works and do exactly what I am expecting. So I read the Release Note and except this [statement](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.19.html#other) :

```
Interface Libraries may now have source files added via add_library() or target_sources(). Those with sources will be generated as part of the build system.
```

nothing seems related to this.

Since I found the CMake 3.18 error, I feel that what I am doing is wrong but I cannot find a better way to express this runtime dependency.

Does anyone have a better idea on how to express this dependency or does it feels right like this ?

Answer (score 0):

In CMake 3.19 and after you could create `b` target for a dll without a lib in a single line:

```
add_library(b INTERFACE "${a_DIR}/bin/b.dll")
```

So when you link `a` with `b`, `a` will get a **dependency from the file** `${a_DIR}/bin/b.dll`.

This is what CMake 3.19 introduces: a dependency of INTERFACE library from the file.

For implement that dependency in CMake pre-3.19, one need to create additional custom target:

```
add_custom_target(b_files DEPENDS "${a_DIR}/bin/b.dll")

add_library(b INTERFACE)
add_dependencies(b b_files)
```

Comment: How can you access the DLL file in order to e.g. install/copy it next to the executable? The TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS generator expression does not seem to contain it for me (using the interface library with CMake >= 3.19).